# How to determine DDVP quality before appplication

Tags: biochemistry, analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis

The question is quite straightforward I need to determine the quality of  2,2-dichlorovinyl dimethyl phosphate (commonly abbreviated as DDVP) it is solved in xylene (50%). The purpose is to know if it can kill the insects. The determination must be fast and an a person with few knowledge of chemistry must be capable of carry it out.

Comment: Are the people who apply the pesticide getting the 2,2-dichlorovinyl dimethyl phosphate dissolved in xylene from different sources? The general notion being that the  2,2-dichlorovinyl dimethyl phosphate concentration varies depending on the source?

Comment: There are three isomers of xylene but density is between 0.86 and 0.88. 2,2-dichlorovinyl dimethyl phosphate has a density of 1.415. So a simple hygrometer test could tell what the % 2,2-dichlorovinyl dimethyl phosphate was. // It seems that this is a nasty pesticide which is not only toxic to insects...